# How can I use nested for loop in r

Tags: r

I have two data frames, appointment and transaction.
Here Chart Number is matching the variable in both data frame.

I need to select `first row` in appointment table and get chart number and appointment date, then match this chart number to transaction table and get all transaction details.
After getting all transaction details, compare appointment date to all transaction dates and if any transaction happened within `15` days then return `1` otherwise return `0` for that particular chart number in appointment table.

How can I use nested for loop or any other functions for this scenario?

I have used the following code

```
for(i in 1:nrow(a))
{
  appt <- a
  chart_number <- a[i, "Chart Number"]
  appointmentdate <- a[i, "Date"]

  trns <- subset(t, "Chart Number" == chart_number) 
  trns1 <- trns["Date"]
  out <- subset(trns1, as.Date(trns1$Date) >= as.Date(appointmentdate) & 
   as.Date(trns1$Date) <= as.Date(appointmentdate) + days(15))

  if(nrow(out) > 0)
  {
    appt$trns <- 1
  } else
    appt$trns <- 0 
}
```

[image]

Appointment table:

Chart number       Date 
1234dt                 26/05/2015
001imp                28/06/2015
Ranj001               03/08/2015
Hath004              06/10/2015

Transaction table

Chart number        Date
1234dt                   26/05/2015
1234dt                   7/06/2015
1234dt                   24/08/2015
001imp                  15/07/2015
001imp                   5/09/2015
Ranj001                  4/08/2015
Ranj001                  29/08/2015

Comment: Please share details of your dataframes. You can use `dput` to generate output. Perhaps you dont need to `for-loop`.

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?rq=1) or at least some sample data.

Comment: I provided the image of sample data

Comment: Please provide the dput ouput and not an image. If it contains crucial data, create a dummy example.

Comment: dput(a) creates the needed ouput :-)

Comment: @Madhusudan Maybe you should accept the answer if it helped you solve your problem so that the question can be considered close.

Comment: Thank you for helping but the answer is relevant but not exact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First transform the 'Date' to a date format:

```
a$Date <- as.Date(a$Date, '%d-%m-%Y')
t$Date <- as.Date(t$Date, '%d-%m-%Y')
```

next use dplyr to do an inner join on the Chart Number

```
library(dplyr)
joined_table <- inner_join(x=a, y=t, by= c('Chart Number' = 'Chart.Number'))
```

Next subtract the two dates and test if the difference is <15 and create a new column Paid.

```
transform(joined_table , Paid = ifelse(Date.y - Date.x <= 15, 1, 0)
```

I did not test this example, because no data was provided. But I guess you get an idea on how you can solve the problem.

I hope I understood your questions correctly.